# How do I set LayoutParams for ImageView

Tags: android, classcastexception, android-layoutparams

I have an ImageView in my app. My question is how I can set params to it?

```
ImageView header = new ImageView(getActivity());
```

I used this way but I face with classCastException

```
ImageView header = new ImageView(getActivity());
header.setImageResource(R.drawable.ahsan_hadis_img);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 1500);
header.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Is your imageview from the layout?

Comment: No, I create it in java code.

Comment: Can you post the XML where you create this ImageView in?

Comment: I haven't any xml for this ImageView. In fact I create it in.java files

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your XML file:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Add this in your JAVA file

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

ImageView subImage = new ImageView(this);
subImage.setLayoutParams(params);              
layout.addView(subImage);
```

Comment: It will work if I have imageView in xml file but my problem is there is no xml file for this ImageView. In fact I create it in .java file

Answer (score 0):

ClassCastException might occur if you are adding your ImageView to a layout other than LinearLayout. Choose your LayourParams [class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) according to the ImageView's parent.